# Use GDAL 2.4 in Geoserver ImageI/O-Ext extension on Windows

Tags: geoserver, gdal, jpeg-2000

Is it possible to use any version of GDAL newer than 1.9.2 in Geoserver on Windows (64bit) to support the ImageI/O-Ext for serving JP2 images?

In 2 days of test I could have the 1.9.2 version running.. ..but any other attempt to use other pakages failed.